# `datetime.strftime` and `datetime.strptime` interprete %Y differently

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-format

I use a statement as shown below to create a `datetime` object from a string:

`t = datetime.strptime("0023-10-10", "%Y-%m-%d")`

Later, somewhere in my code uses the `t` object and invoke the `strftime` method with the same format string:

`t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

This causes a `ValueError: year=23 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900`.

It seems that the validation of the %Y input is different in this two similar methods.
So I have to do the following to make sure I don't accept some bad years like `23`:

```
try:
    format = "%Y-%m-%d"
    t = datetime.strptime("0023-10-10", format)
    t.strftime(format)
except ValueError:
    ...
```

I wonder if there's a better way to do this validation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like your idea of using a `try..except` to validate the input, since in some future version of Python, years < 1000 might be acceptable.

[This comment](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/bf51e32b2a81/Lib/datetime.py#l1192) in the code suggests this restriction is limited to Python's current implementation of strftime.

---

In Python 2.7, the exception occurs for `years < 1900`, but
in Python 3.2, the exception occurs for `years < 1000`:

```
import datetime as dt
format = "%Y-%m-%d"
t = dt.datetime.strptime("0023-10-10", format)
try:
    t.strftime(format)
except ValueError as err:
    print(err)
```

prints

```
year=23 is before 1000; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1000
```

Comment: I still don't understand why this restriction is not applied to `strptime`.

Comment: `datetime.strftime` ultimately calls some C function, `strftime.` The implementation used is restricted to years >= 1900, or 1000 depending on the version of Python. strptime is implemented in Python, and does not have the same restriction. See this [feature request](http://bugs.python.org/issue1777412).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply check `if t.year < 1900` and if it is return an error. No need to deliberately cause an exception.

Comment: Thx for replying. By the way, do you have any idea why these to method behave differently?