# NameError: global name 'program_startdate' is not defined

Tags: python

I am working on my python script to get the list of time formats that I stored in sqlite3 database.

I have got a problem with the variable `program_startdate` which is under the loop `for each row in programs`.

When I try this:

```
#get the programs list
cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs WHERE channel=?', [channel])
programList = list()
programs = cur

for row in programs:
   program = row[1].encode('ascii'), str(row[2]), str(row[3])
   program_startdate = (str(row[2]))
   program_endDate = (str(row[3]))
   programList.append(program)
   print(str(row[2]))
cur.close()

idx = str(programList)

# find nearest half hour
viewStartDate = datetime.datetime.now()
viewStartDate -= datetime.timedelta(minutes = viewStartDate.minute % 30, seconds = viewStartDate.second)

#convert the datetime object between start and end date
startDelta = program_startDate - viewStartDate
stopDelta = program_endDate - viewStartDate
```

I tried to get the variable `program_startdate` outside of the loop, but I get an error:  NameError: global name 'program_startDate' is not defined.

The error are jumping on this line:

```
startDelta = program_startDate - viewStartDate
```

Can you please advice me how I can get the variable outside of the loop?

**EDIT: it show like this:**

```
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140520170000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140520173000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140520200000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140520230000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521000000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521003000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521010000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521013000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521020000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521023000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521030000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521040000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521043000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521050000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521053000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521060000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521063000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521070000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521073000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521080000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521083000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521090000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521110000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521120000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521123000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521130000
19:00:06 T:5028  NOTICE: 20140521133000
```

Comment: Do you want to compute the startDelta for each program?  In that case, you would want to move the startDelta = ... line into your for loop.

Comment: @chishaku yes of course I do. Can you please tell me what change i need to make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your time-related computations into your for loop to compute for each program in your list.

```
#get the programs list
cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs WHERE channel=?', [channel])
programList = list()
programs = cur.fetchall()

for row in programs:
    program = row[1].encode('ascii'), str(row[2]), str(row[3])

    program_startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(row[2]), "%Y%m%d%M%S")
    program_endDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(row[3]), "%Y%m%d%M%S")
    programList.append(program)
    print(str(row[2]))

    # find nearest half hour
    viewStartDate = datetime.datetime.now()
    viewStartDate -= datetime.timedelta(minutes = viewStartDate.minute % 30, seconds = viewStartDate.second)

    #convert the datetime object between start and end date
    startDelta = program_startDate - viewStartDate
    stopDelta = program_endDate - viewStartDate
    print startDelta, stopDelta   # check if you're getting the result you want

cur.close()

idx = str(programList)
```

Comment: thank you very much, but i get an error: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'` for this line `startDelta = program_startdate - viewStartDate`. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: You need to convert the program_startDate from string object to datetime object.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8294907/datetime-strftime-and-datetime-strptime-interprete-y-differently

Comment: i have looked at that link you sent me, but it didn't tell me how to convert from string object to datetime object like my code. can you please tell me how to convert it using my code?

Comment: I need an example of program_startdate.

Comment: here is the example string of program_startdate `201408225000`

Comment: 2014 is the year, 08 is the month, 22 is the day.  What is 5000?

Comment: 50 is the minutes and the 00 is the seconds.

Comment: I updated the code to convert your program_startdate and program_enddate strings to datetime objects using datetime.striptime()

Comment: Thank you very much but i get an error: `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be string, not long.` The error are jumping on this line: `program_startdate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[2], "%Y%m%d%M%S")`. Any idea?

Comment: Thank you, but now i get a different error `TypeError: attribute of type 'NoneType' is not callable`. Any idea why i get the error?

Comment: I still get the same error after I replaced from `programs = cur` to `programs = cur.fetchall()`. any idea?

Comment: You need to verify that your query is actually returning the expected results from the database.  NoneType can signify that the startdate or enddate is NULL in the database.

Comment: how I can verify that my query is actually returning the results?

Comment: you can start at the command line - sqlite3 your_database.sqlite  - then SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs WHERE channel='channel';

Comment: still the same, any idea?

Comment: you mean like this? `cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs WHERE channel='channel'')` if so yes i did. i can print the `program = row[1].encode('ascii'), str(row[2]), str(row[3]) print program`, but i can't print the `print datetime.datetime.strptime(str(row[2]), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")`. any idea?

Comment: It show like `20140520170000, 20140520173000, 20140520200000, 20140520230000`. Please see in my first post for full results.

Comment: It doesn't print this: NOTICE: 20140521133000 ?

Comment: No it doesn't but it will show them when i print them. You can see the date format which it will show like `20140520170000, 20140520173000, 20140520200000, 20140520230000`.

Comment: do you have any idea what i need to do with my code to fix the problem?

Comment: do you have any idea?

Comment: From what I can see, datetime.datetime.strptime(str(row[2]), "%Y%m%d%H%M%S") should work if the string is str(row[2]) = 20140520173000

Answer (score 2):

Those variables will not be defined if `programs` yields no objects (i.e., if it is an empty list, tuple, query with no results, etc.)

You'll need to write your code to handle that case as well (which is a highly problem dependent process).

Comment: Those variables are defined as I have print the list of strings, but i can't get the variable name outside of the loop. Any idea how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The variable "programs", in your case, happens to be an empty iterable, so the loop ends before it starts, leaving any variables defined within the loop undefined.

A good way to fix this is to do this:

```
program_startdate = <a good default>
program_enddate = <a good default>

for row in programs:
    ...
    program_startdate = ...
    program_enddate = ...
```

Comment: Can you please change the code as i don't really get what you mean by a good default? what is the correct way to use the snippet?

Comment: @user3757279, `<a good default>` just means something that would make sense in your program given that the value of the variable doesn't change due to `programs` being empty.